# C# importing MySql with Xamarin

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin

So I have encountered a problem.
I tried to add this while using Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

This sadly doesn't work. Does anybody know how you can import MySql with Xamarin?

Comment: Hi! Please detail how "this doesn't work": any error message? import error for instance?

Comment: It says that I`m missing an assembly reference

Comment: I don't believe that MySQL has a Xamarin compatible library.  Most people use SQLite on the device instead.

Answer (score 2):

Since Xamarin is used for mobile applications I assume there is simply no version of a MySQL database client available which runs on the .NET subset used in Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Android.

Usually mobile applications **do not connect to a database server** directly. They read and write data through a Web API service (e.g. REST or SOAP) instead.

It's bad practice due to security issues to allow the direct access to a database server over the internet to everybody who is using your app. You would need to store database credentials inside the app. Attackers could easily get these credentials in order to manipulate the database. 
I highly recommend to reconsider the system's architecture.